# cross-encoding XSL transformations

Tags: xslt, encoding, character-encoding

I have some operations to do on an XML files (nothing important) and XSL applies very well in this case.
However, my input file is encoded in UTF-8 and the file after the transformation MUST be encoded in iso-8859-1. (I do not control the encoding of the input file either)

Everything goes well except that some special characters present in utf-8 and not in iso-8859 are escaped in the output file.

For instance I have
`<text>some text with a € character</text>`
transformed in 
`<text>some text with a &#8364; character</text>`

The "€" is in the output file is an issue for me.

As we have to do something with those special characters which are not in ISO, I first thought of transforming them manually with the replace function: replace(., '€', 'euros')
But there are just so many characters in utf-8 which are not in iso that it's quickly boring... and slow!

Do you have a better solution ? (assuming we could just remove those characters or transforming them to any viable iso character)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what the problem is? Why is an escaped character like `&#8364;` a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have

```
<xsl:output encoding="iso-8859-1" />
```

in place?

Because that should be all you need, really. If your XSL processor does not correctly translate characters to the target encoding on its own, it is broken and you need to use a different one.

Hints

- Often `Windows-1252` is what people *really* mean when they say `ISO-8859-1`. Check closely if that applies to you as well. There are subtle differences between the two *(especially with regard to the Euro sign, which does not exist in `ISO-8859-1`, but does exist in `Windows-1252` and `ISO-8859-15`)*.
- Whenever an XML declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>` is missing in an XML file, UTF-8 encoding is assumed. Be sure to put a declaration on top of your file whenever is *not* UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: it sounds like he's already getting correct ISO-8859-1 output. He just doesn't like how characters that are not in ISO 8859-1 are being escaped.

Comment: @Lars: I would expect that UTF-8 character `€` (0x20ac) is translated to ISO-8859-15 (8859-1 does not even have the Euro sign) character `€` at `0xa4`, and not to `&#8364;`, which does not even have a meaning in 8-bit encodings.

Comment: @Lars: Then again, `&#8364;` appears to work. Unsurprisingly, now that I think about it. So yeah, you are probably right. (And my suspicion that the OP does not really want `iso-8859-1` might be right as well, because in `Windows-1252` the character comes out as a regular `€` sign when I test it.)

Comment: Hi everyone, sorry for the late comeback...
@MArtin Honnen: An escaped character is a pb for me because the application I want to use after my transformation does not accept it (it just crashes...) And as I don't have a hand on this application I need to solve this problem in the transformation.
@Tom that's exactly it!
@Lars You're correct ISO_8859-1 does not have the € symbol but that's the encoding I have to use anyway.
Just so you know, maybe it can help someone out there, here is how I (quick)fixed it.

Comment: Just so you know, maybe it can help someone out there, here is how I (quick)fixed it.
`<xsl:value-of select="translate($input_text,'€‘’‚“”–—ŒœŠšŸƒ„†‡•…‰™','E``,&quot;&quot;--?????????????')" />`
I translate each utf-8 which does not have an equivalent in iso in another character present in iso.
That's not what I would call a nice solution but it works for me.