# Encoding Issues in XSL Transformation

Tags: xslt, encoding

I have Encoding issues similar to those discussed here : [cross-encoding XSL transformations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495875/cross-encoding-xsl-transformations)

No clean answer was given to these questions; that's why I'm asking it again.

I have an XML input file encoded in UTF8.
I have a XSL Transformation to apply to these files which should generate an XML ouptput encoded in Windows-1252.

I have the two declarations below in my XSLT file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='Windows-1252'?>

<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" encoding="Windows-1252"/>
```

I use Saxon as the XSL processor.
Besides all of that, I still have fatal errors each time a UTF8 charac whith no Windows-1252 equivalent is encountered.
Actually, I don't really care about these characters and my transformation could dropp all of them. I just want the transformation goes on and don't crash because of them.

Where I miss something ? Why still have this fatal errors (Fatal Error! Output character not available in this encoding) ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message you describe is produced only with the text output method (with XML or HTML, the serializer would use numeric character entities). This error is required by the specification
(see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization/#TEXT_ENCODING), though I can understand why you might want a gentler fallback, e.g. outputting a substitute character.

If you don't mind a bit of Java coding, it would be easy to substitute your own version of Saxon's TEXTEmitter that does things differently (you only need to override one method); alternatively, you could send the XSLT output to a Java Writer (the encoding would then be ignored), and use the Java I/O framework to convert characters to the required encoding, with whatever handling of invalid characters your application requires.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer.
Second shame on me for the delay of my feedback...
Third, to be honest i'd like to prevent us from adding more layers to our process.
Finally we chose to use combination of XPath and regular expression (ie: ) to apply specific "re-encode" templates.
But your suggestion on subsitute some methodes on Saxon is pretty fun, I may try this to improve our implementation.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 is a larger character set then Windows-1252

This means some UTF-8 characters can not be translated to windows-1252

Ask yourself why you need to transform between encodings

Comment: Actually, I even can try to answer to myself :-)

Comment: Input encoding is coming from XML web collected files and output is fixed by the final application.
I could use specific reencoding methods outside XSLT if needed, but i'm surprised to not find a XSLT solution. 
Still, I don't care about re-encoding these characs, just escaping them is fine.