# xslt transformation for french text

Tags: text, xslt-2.0, transformation

I am woking on xslt transformation for french text. 
Here i am facing an issue while displaying acute text. Like i tried to display é . According to ISO-8859-1 charecter set which i found in: 
http://www.roubaixinteractive.com/PlayGround/XSLT/HTML_Characters.asp 
the code is é but  when i am displaying it I am getting A© in the output.
I am using xsl 2.0 version and there is also "UTF Coding" mentioned.

### Thanks

Comment: What's the encoding of the source XML file and what output encoding are you using in your XSLT? Please share your input XML and your XSLT

Comment: Spend half an hour searching the Web for basic information on ISO 8859, Unicode, and UTF-8.  The W3C Internationalization Activity has [some good tutorial information](http://www.w3.org/International/getting-started/characters) that may help.

Answer (score 0):

You should check what encoding your source XML is using, for example when it says:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

The encoding of your input is ofcourse ISO-885-1, if the encoding attribute is missing the encoding should be UTF-8 as that is the default encoding.

Also make sure to use the correct encoding output in your XSLT:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
```

Maybe also the following links will help you on your way:

- http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_encoding.asp
- [cross-encoding XSL transformations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495875/cross-encoding-xsl-transformations)
- [Encoding Issues in XSL Transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160511/encoding-issues-in-xsl-transformation)

If you want to be able to map some characters, you can use `<xsl:character-map>`